# Unbalanced dataset in regression rather than classification

Tags: machine-learning

Assume that we have a labeled dataset with inputs and outputs, where the output range is $\left[0, 2\right]$, but the majority of outputs is in $\left[0, 1\right]$. Should one adopt some kind of over- or undersampling approach after compartmentalising the output space to make the dataset more balanced? That would usually be done in classification, but does it apply to regression problems, too? 
Thanks in advance!